# Starting position at bottom of MooTools slider class instead of top

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a way to hook into the MooTools Slider class, so the starting position of the knob is at the bottom (step 0) of the bar and you drag the knob up to get to the top of the bar (step 100).

This is what I have so far:

```
var slider1 = new Slider('#bar', '#knob', {
    offset: 6,
    steps: 100,
    mode: 'vertical'
});
```

And what I need:

```
slider1.startingPosition = 'bottom';
```

Or something to that affect.

Comment: Can you adapt this fiddle to show your problem better? http://jsfiddle.net/FuJ7J/

Comment: Do you mean the fiddle I posted doesn't work for you?

Comment: Never mind here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/n5XF6/ As you can see when you init the slider and set initial step to 1, it's at the top of the bar not the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since steps is defined to 100, your max value is 100, which is what you want to set as `initialStep` (the slider starting point).

For your specific CSS I would remove (or add it womewhere else) the margin on the element of the slider, so it wont shift the slider.

This worked for me:

```
var slider = $('bar');

var slider1 = new Slider(slider, slider.getElement('.knob'), {
    offset: 6,
    steps: 100,
    initialStep: 100,
    mode: 'vertical',
    onChange: function (step) {
        console.log(step);
    }
});
```

And changed also margin top here to 0px:     `margin: 0px 0 0 -7px;`

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64PVG/)

Comment: This is extremely close to what I wanted, however the slider is going to be used as a volume control. If I set the initialStep to 100 than the volume knob will be all the way down, and the audio will be up.

Comment: @NathanBishop, then you can just use `100-step`. Like this: __http://jsfiddle.net/qvJ64/__

Comment: I feel a little embarrassed. Such a simple solution. Thanks for your help.